# How can I load an assembly in PowerShell 5.1 that references EFCore?

Tags: c#, powershell, entity-framework-core, assembly-binding-redirect

I am working on a C# solution which uses Entity Framework Core for the persistence layer. One of the projects I am building is a binary PowerShell module (written in C#), which references my persistence layer project.

When I compile and test the module in a PowerShell window, the first time I try to run any code that references EFCore, I receive this error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException:  Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

There are two projects - Persistence and PowerShell. Both are .NET Standard 2.0 projects, and the PowerShell project references the Persistence project. There are also a few NuGet dependencies (including the EFCore dependencies in the Persistence project). Both projects are using the new `PackageReference` format.

Previously, I had created the PowerShell project as .NET Framework 4.7.2 and experienced the same issue. One of the troubleshooting steps I tried was re-creating the project as a .NET Standard 2.0 project instead.

Another troubleshooting step I've tried is adding the NuGet package `System.ComponentModel.Annotations`. Visual Studio will not let me install an older version than 4.5.0 due to EFCore's dependencies, but I did try installing version 4.5.0 in both the Persistence and the PowerShell projects.

I am using Windows PowerShell 5.1 and .NET Framework 4.7.2 on my workstation. I am aware that PowerShell 6 provides better support for .NET Standard, but unfortunately, moving to PowerShell 6 is not an option for this project due to other dependencies.

I have seen several examples of this error message and assembly related to EF Core and .NET Standard:

- https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/33643
- https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13268

Unfortunately, most of the suggested solutions in those threads describe setting up assembly binding redirects in an app.config file. As I am building a PowerShell module and not a compiled executable, I don't have an app.config file available to set up this redirect.

Can I set up a binding redirect in code to point to the correct version of `System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll`?

Is there another way I can get Windows PowerShell to load the correct version of the assembly for the EFCore functionality?

Answer (score 0):

We experienced the same problem when building a .net standard module that was meant to work in PowerShell core and PowerShell 5 when loading the module into PowerShell 5. .Net standard version of System.ComponentModel.Annotations requires a binding redirect from 4.2.0 to 4.2.1. Nuget adds this to your app.config (in case of .net framework target) but it is not respected when the PowerShell process loads the dll. The only way to make it work was to

1. Add System.ComponentModel.Annotations package, so System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll gets copied to your bin directory or publish folder.
2. Use this code to explicitly load and redirect to the correct version of the dll:

```
    public class ModuleInitializer : IModuleAssemblyInitializer
    {
        public void OnImport()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new AssemblyRedirector().EventHandler;
        }
    }

    public class AssemblyRedirector
    {
        static string AssemblyDirectory
        {
            get
            {
                var codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
                var uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
                var path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
                return Path.GetDirectoryName(path)!;
            }
        }

        static AssemblyRedirector()
        {
            if (Environment.Version.Major <= 4)
            {
                try
                {
                    Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(AssemblyDirectory, "System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll"));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }
        }

        public AssemblyRedirector() => EventHandler = AssemblyResolve;

        public readonly ResolveEventHandler EventHandler;

        Assembly? AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs resolveEventArgs)
        {
            foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            {
                var pattern = "PublicKeyToken=(.*)$";
                var info = assembly.GetName();

                var requestedAssemblyName = new AssemblyName(resolveEventArgs.Name);
                if (StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(requestedAssemblyName.Name, info.Name))
                {
                    if (Regex.IsMatch(info.FullName, pattern))
                    {
                        var matches = Regex.Matches(info.FullName, pattern);
                        var publicKeyToken = matches[0].Groups[1];

                        if (resolveEventArgs.Name.EndsWith("PublicKeyToken=" + publicKeyToken, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            return assembly;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

This actually redirects all assemblies to the loaded version, but one can surely rescrict this in `AssemblyResolve` if needed.